# Simulate Printer Errors / Printed Pages Signals

Tags: printing, driver, printers, spooler

I'm testing software that sends jobs to the printer queue and then rises a flag when they are successfully printed. It also needs to detect how many pages printed correctly in a failed job.

Although there are many "Virtual Printers" out there, they all process their jobs perfectly... And that's the problem.

Is there a printer simulator that can provide with control over the signals it sends back to the windows spooler, such as printed pages, out of paper errors, paper jams, etc?

I'm not interested in the raw output the printer driver handles to the printer, but rather the signals the driver passes back to the windows' spooler.